# Get percentage of total using sub selection

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a query that sums sold units and groups them by store. See code and/or SQL-fiddle below:

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!5/95f29/6

```
SELECT stores,
  sum(shoes) as sold_shoes,
  sum(gloves) as sold_gloves,
  sum(trousers) as sold_trousers,
 
  sum(shoes) +
  sum(gloves) +
  sum(trousers) as sold_total

  FROM t
  GROUP BY stores
```

However, I also want the percentage sold by each unit to the total and have therefore created a column named "sold_total". After the output of this query is generated I need to save it and do another query to get the percentage, see below:

```
select *, 
round(cast(sold_shoes AS FLOAT)/cast(sold_total AS FLOAT)*100,2) as sold_shoes_perc,
round(cast(sold_gloves AS FLOAT)/cast(sold_total AS FLOAT)*100,2) as sold_gloves_perc,
round(cast(sold_trousers AS FLOAT)/cast(sold_total AS FLOAT)*100,2) as sold_trousers_perc
from t_new
```

There's got to be a way to "merge" these two queries into one, and from my understanding, you could use sub-queries which I have tried but given the small SQL-knowledge I haven't got it t work.

Any help out there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, I have a solution for you. You can use CTE. Here is my code given Below

```
CREATE TABLE t([id] int, [stores] varchar(20),  [shoes] int, [gloves] int, [trousers] int );
    
INSERT INTO t([id], [stores], [shoes], [gloves], [trousers]) VALUES
    (1, 'New York', 4, 5, 7),
    (2, 'New York', 5, 1, 1),
    (3, 'New York', 2, 2, 4),
    (4, 'New York', 0, 5, 6),
    (5, 'Boston', 4, 4, 6),
    (6, 'Boston', 9, 3, 5),
    (7, 'Boston', 1, 2, 4),
    (8, 'Washington', 2, 5, 1),
    (9, 'Washington', 5, 2, 5);

WITH CTE AS
    (
      SELECT stores,
          sum(shoes) as sold_shoes,
          sum(gloves) as sold_gloves,
          sum(trousers) as sold_trousers,
         
          sum(shoes) +
          sum(gloves) +
          sum(trousers) as sold_total
    FROM t
    GROUP BY stores
      )
      Select CTE.*,
             (cast(sold_shoes AS FLOAT)/cast(sold_total AS FLOAT) *100.0 ) AS sold_shoesPercentage,
             (cast(sold_gloves AS FLOAT)/cast(sold_total AS FLOAT) *100.0 ) AS sold_glovesPercentage,
             (cast(sold_trousers AS FLOAT)/cast(sold_total AS FLOAT) *100.0 ) AS sold_trousersPercentage
      from CTE
```

**Note:** This code is written in SQLite. Please check the link => [sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!5/95f29/33)

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for a CTE or subquery, or even type casting.
This can be done with simple aggregation:

```
SELECT stores,
       SUM(shoes) sold_shoes,
       SUM(gloves) sold_gloves,
       SUM(trousers) sold_trousers,
       SUM(shoes + gloves + trousers) sold_total,
       ROUND(100.0 * SUM(shoes) / SUM(shoes + gloves + trousers), 2) sold_shoes_perc,
       ROUND(100.0 * SUM(gloves) / SUM(shoes + gloves + trousers), 2) sold_gloves_perc,
       ROUND(100.0 * SUM(trousers) / SUM(shoes + gloves + trousers), 2) sold_trousers_perc
FROM t
GROUP BY stores;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=07966f83ba635a026f53840a6335a4f5).